# Display HTML String as a web page in a Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Here's my Java script code. I want to display my HTML string which is stored in `content`, I want this to be displayed in the iframe instead it displaying from the src url.

How do I do it.

Code:

```
if ($("#wikiframe").length == 0) {
                var s = "";
                s = getSelText();
                var content = "<html>" + s + "</html>";
                if (s == "") {
                    var s = prompt("Forget something?");
                }
                if ((s != "") && (s != null)) {
                    $("body").append("\
                    <div id='wikiframe'>\
                        <div id='wikiframe_veil' style=''>\
                            <p>Loading...</p>\
                        </div>\
                        <iframe src='???' onload=\"$('#wikiframe iframe').slideDown(500);\">Enable iFrames.</iframe>\
                        <style type='text/css'>\
                            #wikiframe_veil { display: none; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25); cursor: pointer; z-index: 900; }\
                            #wikiframe_veil p { color: black; font: normal normal bold 20px/20px Helvetica, sans-serif; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; width: 10em; margin: -10px auto 0 -5em; text-align: center; }\
                            #wikiframe iframe { display: none; position: fixed; top: 10%; left: 10%; width: 80%; height: 80%; z-index: 999; border: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5); margin: -5px 0 0 -5px; }\
                        </style>\
                    </div>");
                    $("#wikiframe_veil").fadeIn(750);
                }
            }
```

`getSelText` would get the string and then I am appending it with `<html>` and `<\html>`.

I want this Html code in `content` to be displayed in the iframe.

How do I do it.

UPDATE:

Please check this JS Fiddle link : I can't figure out why its not working . Added changes as suggested by @mathew.

Answer (score 4):

Put your code as data:uri onto *src* attribute:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: could you give me an example

Comment: If you open the link, you'll see an example with "window.open". This is the one you should experiment with.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on eRIZ's answer, if you have a string of html content "htmlString" and an iframe with the id of "wikiframe" you can inject the HTML code with the following snippet:

`$('#wikiframe').attr('src','data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(htmlString));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use usual jquery functions on `iframe`'s document.

```
$("body").append("<iframe id='wikiframe'></iframe>");
var s = getSelText();
$("#wikiframe").contents().find('body').append(s);
```

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/37WRC/) Please check this, I can't still figure why doesn't it run...!!

Comment: Your iframe id is `wikiIDframe` not `wikiframe` so change above code accordingly. You are removing the `wikiframe` div inside a `setTimeout` which is the parent of your `iframe` and hence everything you added will be removed with it. You are setting `position:fixed` style for iframe and `height` in percentage of parent, which will be zero since child is not relative to parent and no other block content is inside it to grow the parent. These are few of the several problems I saw in there.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, any html content you append to an `iframe` gets displayed when the iframe is **NOT** supported by the browser