# Need to place whole HTML5 code inside div or iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a complete HTML5 page in a JSON object, I have to show it to my page inside a div or iframe. Following is sample code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window._reviewWidget = {
            onReady: function () {
                var block1 = {
                    voyagerId:"xxxxxxx",
                    container: "container",
                    flavour:"small"
                };
                _reviewWidget.loadReview(block1);
            }
        };
        (function (W,i,D,G,E,T)
        {
            W[G] = W[G] || {};
            T = i.getElementsByTagName(D)[0];
            E =i.createElement(D);
            E.async = 1;
            E.src ='/js/reviewWidget.js';


            T.parentNode.insertBefore(E, T);
        })(window, document,'script','_reviewWidget');
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I am trying to put the code in div or iframe getting just container div, header part and body, HTML tag missing. I know we can't put such tags in div so I tried an iframe as well. But same issue either can see whole code as text or just container div.

Iframe code i am using (html_code JS variable with above HTML code)

**Type-1**

```
$('#HtmlFrame').contents().find('body').html(html_code);
```

**Type-2**

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
var ctnr = document.getElementById('Ewidget');
ctnr.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.contentWindow.document.open('text/htmlreplace');
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html_code);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display HTML String as a web page in a Iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313101/display-html-string-as-a-web-page-in-a-iframe)

Comment: *"I have complete html5 page in a JSON object"* - that's impossible. Did you mean you have a string containing HTML markup?

Comment: _"I have complete html5 page in a JSON object"_ Can you include `JSON` at Question? Not certain what expected result is?  Six parameters are expected at `(function (W,i,D,G,E,T)` though only four are passed at `})(window, document,'script','_reviewWidget');`?

Comment: HTML code i am using is complete widget code, saved in database. I just need to place the widget in div/iframe.